# Message Queue in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, message-queue

Can multiple processes communicate through Message Queues or is it only for multiple thread communication ? I want to let two different processes communicate. I don t want to use shared memory because of some reasons. I want to use message queues instead. Is is doable ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Call the [`PostMessage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) to add a message to the queue for a window, or [`PostThreadMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946.aspx) to add a message to the queue for a thread. (Obviously, the thread must be running a message loop.)

The [`WM_COPYDATA` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011.aspx) is explicitly designed for this purpose. It does the marshaling for you. Of course, it is a pretty basic form of marshaling: all it knows how to do is marshal a blob of bytes. It's your responsibility to interpret that blob of bytes into something useful.

There is a complete example of copying data between processes [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649009.aspx).

It is also worth pointing out that you don't even need `WM_COPYDATA` if the amount of information that you want to pass is so small that it will fit inside of `wParam` or `lParam`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Message Queing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a construct for inter process communication (IPC).

You can build a data construct in the memory of one process that even can implement a queue. This can be use for quick processing e.g. for [Windows messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This must be differentiated from MSMQ.

Comment: Thanks. But in some resources, message queue is mentioned as IPC method.